# Appropriate practice for security-constraint in web.xml

Tags: authorization, security, web.xml, security-constraint

I can restrict access to web application through defining (among other things) `security-constraint` in web.xml. Each security-constraint consist of 1) `<web-resource-collection>` which contains a set of restricted resources, and 2) `<auth-constraint>` which contains a set of authorized users (security roles) which can access web-resource-collection defined in this constraint .

So I think I can do either in each constraint a) define single resource (address) and a set of authorized users or b) define a set of resources (addresses) and a single authorized user.

Am I right? What my approach should be.

I for example defined constrains like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>ConstraintAdminUser</display-name>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>adminResources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/protected/main/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/protected/user/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/protected/lang/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>AdminUserRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>ConstraintUserOnly</display-name>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>userResources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/main/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/protected/user/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/protected/lang/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>UserOnlyRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>
```

But I don't know if it is a "right way" to do :)